# ETL - Automate Data Transfer from One Database to another

Tags: json, database, oracle11g, nosql, arangodb

I'm well versed in data and how to move and manipulate data however the processes I've been using for 5 to 6 years now are mostly manual.  While there are plenty of macro's, queries, functions and other methods pre-coded to assist with moving and manipulating the data into my Oracle database the entire process cannot be done unless an individual is there to make it happen.

My question here is asking to know the many ways as to how one would automate the process of moving data out of one system and into another.  I'm positive this can be done via a file drop from one system and then have the files picked up by the other system.  Or perhaps one system can utilize the other systems API and simply pull the data out and import it into itself.  The other option is to push the data out and have the source system access the destination system via it's API.  I have little experience in automating data transfers and just need some direction.  How do these large and small companies automate their data transfers?  What are my options?

While I'm looking for generalized answers my situation is specific to moving data out of Oracle and into an Arango NoSQL database in a JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how we do that; we have customers that pay for our services in different banks. Each of those banks delivers TXT files that contains payments from the previous day; those files are located in a directory (folder).

There's the operating system scheduled job (on MS Windows, that's Task Scheduler) which runs every few minutes and check whether there's a new file in that directory.

If so, it runs a (MS DOS) batch script which calls Oracle SQL*Loader utility. It then loads data into an Oracle table and copies the TXT file into the archive directory.

Not exactly a rocket science, but - works for years now.

I'm sure that someone else will have different examples & suggestions.